# select a terraform module depending on the variable value

Tags: terraform

I want to select a module depending on the value of the input variable from the user:

```
var.value ? "a" = {
module case1
{source="/env/cluster1"}
}

var.value ? "b" = {
module case1
{source="/env/cluster2}
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use count argument of modules to create that many instances of module depending on variable's value. For example,

```
module "servers" {
  source = "/env/cluster1"
  count = var.value == "a" ? 1: 0
}
module "servers" {
      source = "/env/cluster1"
      count = var.value == "b" ? 1: 0
    }
```